# Unable to get to a point in Yeti Valley

Tags: far-cry-4

I'm trying to reach a certain high point in Yeti Valley and I just can't see how it's done. I provide a SS and perhaps some one can help. It's marked with a red ring.

[image: Unaccessable point marked]

Comment: I dont understand, what have you tried?